# How do I use data that I fetched from DB in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

So I'm using useEffect hook to fetch my data from database and after I get that data I want to set it as useState for title and postBody, but it doesn't work, because useEffect hook runs "last", how can I fix it?

Code:

```
const [cPost, setCPost] = useState([]);
  const postId = id.match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
      .then(posts => {
        setCPost(posts.data);
        console.log("SAS");
      })
  }, []);

   const [title, setTitle] = useState(cPost.title);
   const [postBody, setPostBody] = useState(cPost.postBody);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary and quick solution, you can use such workaround:

```
const [cPost, setCPost] = useState();
const [title, setTitle] = useState();
const [postBody, setPostBody] = useState();

const postId = id.match.params.id;

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
    .then(post => {
      setCPost(post.data);
      console.log("SAS");
    })
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(cPost) {
    setTitle(cPost.title);
    setPostBody(cPost.postBody);
  }
}, [cPost]);
```

Or the second option:

```
const [cPost, setCPost] = useState();
const [title, setTitle] = useState();
const [postBody, setPostBody] = useState();

const postId = id.match.params.id;

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+postId)
    .then(post => {
      setCPost(post.data);
      setTitle(post.title);
      setPostBody(post.postBody);
      console.log("SAS");
    })
}, []);
```

But in the future I would recommend doing `side effects` like `API` requests and others using special libraries or create `hook` for making `API` requests.

For example [`redux-saga`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga) or [`redux-thunk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk).

And use a state manager like [`redux`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux) or [`mobx`](http://npmjs.com/package/mobx).

P.S. and consider whether you need to store the `title` and `body` separately in the component `state`. I have a strong suspicion that you have no need for it.